# Salesforce[Web Tab]: how to authorize user

Tags: salesforce

I have created Web Tab in salesforce with url of my application. When someone opens that tab and my application gets call, How can I make sure where user who opened it is authorized?

I know I can pass {!User.Email} and other variables to my app to identify user. I guess some sites also send {!Api.SessionId} but I can not find any information about how to authorize using Api.SessionId or any other variables that can be passed.

Update
I found https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign_On_for_Composite_Apps which is guide to the question I asked. But not able to find jar for given java classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the API SessionID and ServerURL to make a request back to Salesforce via the API. Say with the PartnerAPI. This will confirm that the user did indeed come from a valid Salesforce session. You can confirm other details, such as their email address from the active session as well.

---

Alternatively, you could create a newer connected app using signed requests. Here the request posted to you app will be signed with using a secret that you can decrypt. This ensures the details haven't been faked or tampered with.

Rather than creating a Composite App you can create a Canvas App. This is a type of Connected App. You can find instructions for setting this up at [Creating a Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_create.htm&language=en_US). The Signed Request is POSTed to your web app. See [Signed Request Authentication](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connectpre/Content/canvas_app_signed_req_authentication.htm)

Comment: How to create app using signed request and how encrypted request is posted. Are you talking about API (Enable OAuth Settings).

Comment: @hridayesh I've expanded my answer with details on creating a connected app and the composition on the signed request.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! But in case of connected canvas app, can it be added as Tab in salesforce?

Comment: @hridayesh Yes, you can create a Visualforce page as a tab and use `<apex:canvasApp>` to display the canvas app. See [Where Canvas Apps appear](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/Content/canvas_apps_where_they_appear.htm)

Comment: In my experience, sometimes newer isn't always better. We just created a Connected App that uses OAuth, but reverted to the `<iframe>`/sessionid approach due to simplicity. In particular, we wanted to make a single VF page to handle desktop browsers and Salesforce1. That is a nightmare in itself :)